# PHP $_GET function is not working on server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress, php7, ubuntu-16.04

I need help with my server. I am using Ubuntu 16 (PHP7 and Nginx are from the official repo) with Wordpress.

I have a sub-domain with SSL installed with a directory theme which has a page template. The settings on the page don't work. It only reloads when you click on the menu.

[dashboards menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8agJ4.png)

The theme developer said it's from the server that PHP $_GET function is not working. The back-end works but that page only.

Does anyone have an idea?

here is the source code from the page http://pastebin.com/48bFyYmi i also followed a suggestion in this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/823648/php-get-function-is-not-working-on-server?noredirect=1#comment1251104_823648

Thanks

Comment: $_GET is not a function, but [an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). You need [to get nginx configured right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689959/nginx-php-fpm-php-works-except-cannot-use-get), just use apache instead of nginx+php-fpm, since nor you, nor your 'developer' have any ideas about properly configuring them. Apache on the other hand "just works" in those situations...

Comment: hello; here is my nginx conf. because its too long i use pastebin http://pastebin.com/zWEpqMX6 also using `try_files /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php;`